CreateFileTransactedW fail, and error code is 6725
I successfully got a transaction handle by CreateTransaction function, then I try to call CreateFileTransactedW with the transaction handle, but failed and get error code 6725 (ERROR_IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Here's my create transaction handle code:
global.transaction_handle = CreateTransaction(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, INFINITE, NULL);

And the CreateFileTransactedW code is:
USHORT miniVer = 0xFFFE; // TXFS_MINIVERSION_DEFAULT_VIEW
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileTransactedW(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile, global.transaction.transaction_handle, &miniVer, NULL);

I wonder why CreateFileTransactedW fail, and want to know how to solve this problem.

You store the transaction in global.transaction_handle, you are then passing global.transaction.transaction_handle?

Yes, I'm sure the value has been passed to global.transaction.transaction_handle

What values are you passing to CreateFileTransactedW? What are lpFileName, dwDeesiredAccess etc. Can you post a minimal, executable code snippet we can use to reproduce the issue?

Microsoft's documentation on system error codes unhelpfully states that this error code stands for "Implicit transaction are not supported.". I suspect that a value you're passing to the function is incorrect. What values are you passing to the function exactly?

@Pink If the transaction specified in hTransaction is not the transaction that is modifying the file, this parameter should be NULL. Please set &miniVer to NULL.

Please [edit] and show a [mcve].
